# iTerm2/tmux smart selection - ignore tmux pane border

Tags: tmux, iterm2

I have enabled iTerm2's smart selection in:

```
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Pointer -> Double-click performs smart selection
```

This works fairly well, except that the tmux pane separator is included in the selection when I double click on a path's line number (I typically do this when I want to select the file and line of a failed compilation).
This can also result in 'corruption' of the pasted text.
See GIF for a better description.

[image: iTerm2 copy paste]

Why do I want to use smart selection?

- It does a better job at selected what I actually want when double clicking
- I can have a consistent way of selecting text both inside- and outside of tmux (option left-click behaves identically).

I have tried creating rules for selection of paths + line number in

```
iTerm2 -> Preferences -> Profiles -> Advanced -> Smart Selection
```

but my ICU regexp fu (https://www.iterm2.com/smartselection.html) is weak.

- iTerm version: Build Build 3.0.10
- tmux version: 2.2

Feedback is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After further grokking of the regex documentation, I find that the following works ok:

```
[[a-z][A-Z][0-9][_:][\.\/\-]]+
```

Debugging iTerm2 regex matching is a bit painful on MacOS Sierra, as selecting "log debug info to console.app" in the Smart Selection Rules editor does not seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to configure this by modifying the default "Word bounded by whitespace" rule from `\S+` to `(?!│)(\S+)`.

This works by negative look-ahead assertion on the `│` character used by tmux between adjacent panes.